# trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libfuse2/Makefile.gz', which is different from other instances of package libfuse2:i386

Tags: dpkg

I have checked with update manager, it shows some simple updates of some useless software and that is also not getting installed and gives the message the broken package and it is irritating me with same message.

It gave me this command `sudo apt-get install -f` after running it says:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  openjdk-7-jre-lib
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libfuse2:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libfuse2:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/138 kB of archives.
After this operation, 323 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 236898 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libfuse2:i386 (from .../libfuse2_2.9.0-1ubuntu3_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libfuse2_2.9.0-1ubuntu3_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libfuse2/Makefile.gz', which is different from other instances of package libfuse2:i386
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libfuse2_2.9.0-1ubuntu3_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Edit your question and include the output of `apt-cache policy libfuse2:i386 libfuse2:amd64`.

Answer (score 0):

1- run `apt-get autoremove` as instructed in your command output

2- follow steps in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SaucyUpgrades

3- you might want to download 13.10 ISO; burn it to a DVD, when inserted; your system will add it an update source and process the upgrade from it (I think it would be better to disconnect from Internet so that you force the update manager NOT TO go online for any repository check.